# Flutter : infinite width

Tags: flutter, constraints

I'm doing a flutter course, and here is my relevent code :

```
Container(
                  color: kBottomContainerColour,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: kBottomContainerHeight,
                ),
```

And I keep getting this :

```
These invalid constraints were provided to _RenderColoredBox's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
  RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:268:14)
The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, h=80.0)
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container file:///F:/Works/Projects/flutter/Flutter-Course-Resources/bmi-calculator-flutter1/lib/input_page.dart:241:24
```

Though it is working fine in the course
Please help

Comment: What is your container within? Is it within a `Row`, `Column`,  or `Stack` widget?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of  `width: double.infinity`,

Use,

```
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
```

Comment: Be careful with MedaiQuery.of(context) because it can cause a page repaint which causes the current input field to lose focus. I call it once at the start of my app and then in the future I just use the cached value.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use **double.infinity**. Use the MediaQuery to get the size from the current widget context, and get the width from that.
In this case do this:

```
Container(color: kBottomContainerColour,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
                  height: kBottomContainerHeight,
                ),
```

Please note that everytime you use **MediaQuery** the widget will reload its state. So make sure break your widgets down, and follow google's performance guidelines:

https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/rendering/best-practices

Answer (score 0):

As of 2024, you can use `MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width` to only redraw on resize:

> Querying using MediaQuery.of will cause your widget to rebuild
> automatically whenever any field of the MediaQueryData changes (e.g.,
> if the user rotates their device). Therefore, unless you are concerned
> with the entire MediaQueryData object changing, prefer using the
> specific methods (for example: MediaQuery.sizeOf and
> MediaQuery.paddingOf).

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html